# Which role controls the object creation in an application?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am designing an application that will create reports based on business rules.

So far there are:

- TableDataGateway (and subordinate classes) to import data and keep it in ready-to-access form as a DataTable
- ModelBuilder to map the data onto individual business models
- IdentityMap to keep track of existing model objects

There will be a WinForms UI which will control the application (to be implemented).

Let there be a use case where the user wants to load specific samples and view their list within the UI.

**The question:** Which class should control the object creation process (data retrieval, construction and IMap registration)? Should all this be handled by the controller within the Presentation Layer (Forms)? Or should some class within the Business layer receive the message from the Presentation Layer and deal with the request?

Comment: Are you using MVC on Winforms?

Comment: I am trying to implement a three-layered architecture, not an MVC one.

Comment: MVC *is* a three-layered architecture... In its core, the separation is always the same:  Data, Logic, and UI. The details very between architectures, but the principal is the same in MVC, MVVM, MVP and any other three-tier architecture implementation.

Comment: Oh, then I probably do not understand the topic properly. My layers are, as you wrote, Data, Logic, and UI.
Why did you ask about MVC on Windows?

Comment: I was asking because from my experience it's rare to see Winforms applications based on MVC - even though Microsoft provides a built-in MVC support for asp.net applications, Winforms have been left out of this loop for some reason. I've worked before on MVP-based winforms apps. Again, these are similar yet different architectures, but all designed to separate your program to three distinct parts - the UI, the data, and the logic.

Comment: what is the ordinary architecture used for WinForms apps then? I am at the beginning, so this is the best time not to learn bad habits. :)

Comment: Winforms is an old technology, some might even say abandoned. Most of modern applications are web-based, and most of the modern desktop-based applications in the .net world are written using the new MAUI (Multi-platform App UI) framework - which is c# and xaml based. (That being said, if your target platform is windows only, you can still use Winforms, though - you might want to favoing MVP over MVC for that). I personally have been focused on backend for the past few years so I don't have any experience with MAUI, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the object creation process should be controlled by dependency injection code written in (or used by) the application entry point - if it's a single assembly application you can simply handle all dependency injection code inside the class that has your entry point method (by default, that would be in the Program class).

With multiple assembly applications (i.e., Micro Services architecture) you might want to create a class dedicated to wrap your IOC container and use it in each assembly's Program class, just to provide a layer of abstraction between your IOC container and your application code. (A lesson learned when switching from one IOC provider to another)

Comment: so do I understand correctly, that not only would the Program class keep methods for individual use-cases, but also keep all the objects necessary? so it is similar to the main function of small-scale scripts, but wrapped inside a class?

and question 2: should this class then be static or is there any advantage of it being non-static?

Comment: From me experience, there's no benefit in creating an instance of the Program class. Moreover, Dot net 6 have introduced top-level statements that enables you to write the code you would previously write in the `static void main(string[] args)` method without the need to actually have the class construct wrapping it (of course, the c# compiler does add that part for you). The program class doesn't need to directly hold references to the objects you're using in your program, just to the IOC container of your choice.